# How to check if a java class has a particular method in it?

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I have an xml schema (generated automatically using trang) which keeps changing. These changes are not very elaborate. Only some elements are added or deleted from this schema. From this schema, I am generating java classes (using cxf) by which I will unmarshall the xml document.

As schema changes, my auto-generated java classes also change. Again, as with schema, changes in java classes are not very big. For instance, if an element say `elemA` is added to schema; some related functions say `getElemA()` and `setElemA()` are added to auto-generated java class.

Now how would I make sure that a particular function exists in these auto-generated classes? One solution is to hand-write the schema such that all possible elements of xml are covered. This is what I'll ultimately do. But for now, I have not fixed the format of xml file.

UPDATE :

There is a possibility that a method `getElemA()` may be defined in auto-generated classes. I do not have control over the auto-generation of these classes. But in my main class, if have following code,

```
If method getElemA exists then 
     ElemA elemA = getElemA()
```

This code will always be there in my main class. If method `getElemA()` is generated in one of the auto-generated class then there is no problem. But if this method is not generated then compilers complain that this method does not exists in any of the class.

Is there any way that I can make compiler not to complain about this function at compile time?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One method is mentioned by @missingfaktor and another is below (if you know the name and parameters of the api).

Say you have one method which takes no args:

```
Method methodToFind = null;
try {
  methodToFind = YouClassName.class.getMethod("myMethodToFind", (Class<?>[]) null);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
  // Your exception handling goes here
}
```

Invoke it if present:

```
if(methodToFind == null) {
   // Method not found.
} else {
   // Method found. You can invoke the method like
   methodToFind.invoke(<object_on_which_to_call_the_method>, (Object[]) null);
}
```

Say you have one method which takes native `int` args:

```
Method methodToFind = null;
methodToFind = YouClassName.class.getMethod("myMethodToFind", new Class[] { int.class });
```

Invoke it if present:

```
if(methodToFind == null) {
   // Method not found.
} else {
   // Method found. You can invoke the method like
   methodToFind.invoke(<object_on_which_to_call_the_method>, invoke(this,
      Integer.valueOf(10)));
}
```

Say you have one method which takes boxed `Integer` args:

```
Method methodToFind = null;
methodToFind = YouClassName.class.getMethod("myMethodToFind", new Class[] { Integer.class });
```

Invoke it if present:

```
if(methodToFind == null) {
   // Method not found.
} else {
   // Method found. You can invoke the method like
   methodToFind.invoke(<object_on_which_to_call_the_method>, invoke(this,
      Integer.valueOf(10)));
}
```

Using the above soln to invoke method won't give you compilation errors.
Updated as per @Foumpie

Comment: Thanks. I want to use the method and I have to write all possible methods in that class but autogenerated class may not have that method. How to make compiler ignore this at compile time?

Comment: Using invoke wont give you compilation errors...check the updated ans.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After enclosing it in `try-catch`, it worked like a charm.

Comment: The 'invoke' used inside first invoke i.e. invoke(this, Integer.valueOf(10))); gives me compilation error that the invoke method is undefined.

Comment: _methodToFind_ will never be NULL, because a NoSuchMethodException will already be thrown.

Comment: pitfall: only public methods will be returned

Answer (score 26):

Use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

boolean hasMethod = false;
Method[] methods = foo.getClass().getMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
  if (m.getName().equals(someString)) {
    hasMethod = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

So you want to invoke the method if it exists. This is how you do it:

```
if (m.getName().equals(someString)) {
  try {
    Object result = m.invoke(instance, argumentsArray);
    // Do whatever you want with the result.
  } catch (Exception ex) { // For simplicity's sake, I am using Exception.
                           // You should be handling all the possible exceptions
                           // separately.
    // Handle exception.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The main trouble is even if I have identify that a method `getA` does note exists, I need to write that function. For example `if methodA exists then methodA()`. It is giving compile time error since this method does not exits. How can I let the compilation goes on and make it a run-time check?

Comment: @Dilawar, you should be perusing some reflection tutorials, because it appears you are going to need it a lot.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look. And you are right about my level of understanding of reflection.

Comment: +1 for being accurate. I agree the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 12):

With Spring:

```
Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(TheClass, "methodName");
if (method != null) {
  //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spring Framework, the simplest way would be to use `ReflectionUtils.findMethod()` utility.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is by using Java 8 stream:

```
  Optional<Method> methodToFind =
                Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods()).
                        filter(method -> "methodName".equals(method.getName())).
                        findFirst();
        if (methodToFind.isPresent()) {
            // invoke method or any logic needed
            ///methodToFind.get().
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection in Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html